# Bash, awk, compare 2 cols divided by , and fields in "

Tags: bash, awk

**System**

```
Linux local 5.0.0-27-lowlatency #28-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 20 20:33:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Question**

How can I compare two cols divided by `,` and fields in `"` when `,` is present in field (classic csv with `"`).

Input file.

```
Titulka,231096,Spárovka borová 18 x 200 x 600 mm,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-drevo-a-wpc-sparovky-sparovka-borova-18x200x600mm/144020p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/231096-sp-rovka-borov-1-pou-t-tuto.jpg,42,45
Titulka,345602,"Lak Aquafin Plus čirý lesklý 0,6 kg",https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-barvy-a-laky-laky-a-lazury-lak-aquafin-plus-ciry-leskly-0-6-kg/153252p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/345602-aquafin-plus-plechovka.jpg,179,199
Titulka,345588,"Lak Movi Pur OSB čirý lesklý 0,6 kg",https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-barvy-a-laky-laky-a-lazury-lak-movi-pur-osb-ciry-leskly-0-6-kg/150470p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/345588.jpg,209,229
Titulka,213993,Schodnice masiv 300x1000x40 mm - smrk,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-schodiste-a-zabradli-schodnice-schodnice-masiv-300x1000x40-mm-smrk/138451p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/213993-schodnice-masiv-300x1000x40-smrk.jpg,299,329
2,233292,Střešní okno plastové kyvné Klasik NK E1 - 55 x 78 cm,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-okna-stresni-okna-stresni-okno-plastove-kyvne-klasik-nk-e1-55-x-78-cm/144206p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/233292-2-.jpg,3990,3990
2,234185,Střešní okno dřevěné kyvné Klasik MNK S1 - 55 x 78 cm,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-okna-stresni-okna-stresni-okna-stresni-okno-drevene-kyvne-klasik-mnk-s1-55-x-78-cm/144478p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/233288-3--4.jpg,2990,2990

...
```

Expected output file (compare `$6` and `$7`, write `$7` when `$6 != $7`).

```
Titulka,231096,Spárovka borová 18 x 200 x 600 mm,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-drevo-a-wpc-sparovky-sparovka-borova-18x200x600mm/144020p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/231096-sp-rovka-borov-1-pou-t-tuto.jpg,42,45
Titulka,345602,"Lak Aquafin Plus čirý lesklý 0,6 kg",https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-barvy-a-laky-laky-a-lazury-lak-aquafin-plus-ciry-leskly-0-6-kg/153252p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/345602-aquafin-plus-plechovka.jpg,179,199
Titulka,345588,"Lak Movi Pur OSB čirý lesklý 0,6 kg",https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-barvy-a-laky-laky-a-lazury-lak-movi-pur-osb-ciry-leskly-0-6-kg/150470p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/345588.jpg,209,229
Titulka,213993,Schodnice masiv 300x1000x40 mm - smrk,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-schodiste-a-zabradli-schodnice-schodnice-masiv-300x1000x40-mm-smrk/138451p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/213993-schodnice-masiv-300x1000x40-smrk.jpg,299,329
2,233292,Střešní okno plastové kyvné Klasik NK E1 - 55 x 78 cm,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-okna-stresni-okna-stresni-okno-plastove-kyvne-klasik-nk-e1-55-x-78-cm/144206p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/233292-2-.jpg,3990 /* here is $6 = $7, so no output for $7 */
2,234185,Střešní okno dřevěné kyvné Klasik MNK S1 - 55 x 78 cm,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-okna-stresni-okna-stresni-okna-stresni-okno-drevene-kyvne-klasik-mnk-s1-55-x-78-cm/144478p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/233288-3--4.jpg,2990 /* here is $6 = $7, so no output for $7 */

...
```

**I tried**

```
awk -F ',' '{ if ($6 != $7) print $7; }' FILE
```

Returns bad values and return only `$7` field.

Thanks.

Comment: Im not sur to well understand the question, please try `awk -F',' '$6!=$7 {print $7}'` and tell me if its ok for you, ill make it an answer

Comment: @cmak.fr Hi, thanks, but this is the same. Problem is that some fields are in doublequotas, `" field"` as one field, but `awk` takes `,` independently on this. For example `345588,"Lak Movi Pur OSB čirý lesklý 0,6 kg",` has `,` inside `""`and it should be take as one field for `awk`. But `awk` separate it by `,`. And how get all values. Simple said, I need just remove last value, if the value is the same as before, for example last 2 fields `...,12,12` ar the same, so return only `...,12`, `...,12,14` are different, so return `...,12,14`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a CSV with commans inside fields, `awk` is not the best solution.
For your example file, you could still use it, because you can simply compare the last two fields and don't care what is there before:

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
$NF==$(NF-1){$NF=""}1
' file
```

But in general, it would be better parsing CSV with a proper CSV parser, e.g. [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.1/install.html):

```
csvsql -H --query '
    SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f, case g when f then NULL else g END g from file
' file | tail -n+2
```

(I added `tail -n+2` to suppress the header row)

---

Note that both solutions will keep the total number of fields, just emptying the last field. To remove the last comma, add `| sed 's/,$//'`.

Comment: Thanks, quite simple good solution, just there is `,` at the end of line, only last value `$7` is removed. How can I remove `,` too in this case? And I can't use `csvsql`, because I don't have root access to install it.

Comment: if you read the full answer ....

Comment: Sorry, thanks. But in case need to do it for fields in the middle of line, is solution for awk for parsing line with doublequotas ""`? Thanks.

Comment: The solution would be to ask your admin to install proper tools to fulfill your job. `csvkit` or some [python `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) would be good. There won't be any good `awk` or `sed` solution for that. Maybe some weird error-prone workaround that works somehow for some cases, but no *real* solution.

Comment: At least with `gawk` and `mawk`, you can decrement `NF` to remove the last field without leaving a trailing delimiter